Cannot physically remove deactivated SIM from iPad Air Gen5, can I still use eSIM?
Cannot physically remove deactivated SIM from iPad Air Gen5, can I still use eSIM?
iPad is encased in an Xciel case and thus deactivated SIM cannot be removed.  Can we still use eSIM?  We cannot reactivate the physical SIM.

yes, they are independent

Follow instructions https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/set-up-cellular-service-ipad9940e098/ipados

Out of curiosity, why can’t you remove the device from the case?

it's an instrinsically safe case, if we take it out of the case then we cannot use the iPad in an industrial environment

You can’t put it back into the case once you remove the SIM?
